# C Program - Efficient way to Print the Linear Rows and Columns

Tags: c, algorithm, printf

I have a array as below,

```
 #define BASE_ADDRESSES  10

 int register_values[BASE_ADDRESSES] = {23, 12, 54, 16, 32, 44, 11, 38, 35, 52};
```

I want to print it like this,

```
Base_Address   Hex_Values        ASCII_Values
------------   -----------       -------------
0x0000         17   0C  36       ')'  '6'  '*'
0x0003         10   20  2C       ' '  ','  '$'
0x0006         0B   26  23       '~'  '&'  '#'
0x0009         34                '4'
```

But it requires Row formatting as well as column formatting, please provide the `printf` formats to do this efficiently..

Note: ASCII values are not correct, just for example..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a `printf` format that will suit your regular lines and your ending line. You have to construct the output piece by piece. You should also cater for unprintable characters and special representations of charcters such as `'\n'` in your character output.

Here's a `dump` routine that formats the output to `col` columns:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static const char *special(int c)
{
    switch(c) {
    case '\0':  return "'\\0'";
    case '\a':  return "'\\a'";
    case '\b':  return "'\\b'";
    case '\n':  return "'\\n'";
    case '\r':  return "'\\r'";
    case '\t':  return "'\\t'";
    case '\v':  return "'\\v'";
    case '\'':  return "'\\''";
    case '\\':  return "'\\\\'";
    }

    return NULL;
}

static int unprintable(int c)
{
    return c < 32 || c > 126;
}

void dump(int arr[], size_t n, size_t col)
{
    size_t base = 0;

    while (n) {
        printf("%08zx        ", base);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < col; i++) {
            if (i < n) {
                printf("%02x ", arr[i]);
            } else {
                fputs("   ", stdout);
            }
        }

        printf("     ");

        for (size_t i = 0; i < col; i++) {
            if (i < n) {
                const char *p = special(arr[i]);

                if (p) {
                    printf("%-5s", p);
                } else if (unprintable(arr[i])) {
                    printf("0%03o ", arr[i]);
                } else {
                    printf("'%c'  ", arr[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        printf("\n");

        arr += col;
        n = (n < col) ? 0: n - col;
        base += col;
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
int main()
{
    int val[] = {23, 12, 54, 16, 32, 44, 11, 38, 35, 52};

    dump(val, 10, 3);

    return 0;
}
```